# Che cosa significa "trovavano il ramo che li scorticava"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Tobia e la padrona furono invitati allo sposalizio e ci andarono portando di regalo due asciugamani. Potevano ben andarci anche Jano e Baldino, cosí avrei potuto starmene una giornata da solo, come n’avevo voglia e bisogno. Invece li ebbi dietro tutto il giorno, che mi tiravano le satire e volevano farmi nientemeno che la porrata, che è una traccia di porri e meliga che si semina verso la porta di chi è stato lasciato da una donna nel giorno che lei si sposa con un altro: uno scherno, ma dissero soltanto di farmelo, perché quel giorno **trovavano il ramo che li scorticava**.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "trovavano il ramo che li scorticava" in questo passaggio? Ho cercato alla voce "ramo" in parecchi dizionari, incluso il dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli, ma non ho trovato nulla a riguardo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

È una minaccia.

Il protagonista dice in pratica che se gli amici avessero fatto questo scherzo sul serio, anziché solo limitarsi ad annunciarlo (*"[...] ma dissero soltanto di farmelo [...]"*), lui li avrebbe presi a bastonate (o a scudisciate) con un ramo fino a levar loro la pelle.